# How do you make a ultra-compact repeating signal for dispensers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friends and I are working on a TF2 map in Minecraft, essentially making different weapons and abilities for classes.

One of the classes we were working on was the Engie, and in Minecraft, there's really no way to make a very compact repeating mechanism.

We already have the dispenser thing set up (dispenser + splash potion of health), but for a turret, we're looking for the most compact way to make it "repeatedly" shoot out arrows.

Comment: If you are modding in new functionality why not a new dispenser that can be turned on to just shoot all the time?

Comment: My friend intends this to be a non-mod, non-texture pack map, so anyone can use it without any hassles.

Comment: @JimmyChen so how are you going to prevent non-engies from placing that repeater? write "engies only" on a chest with materials? You should at least have a look at something like bukkit permissions, where you can make sure only certain players can use specific blocks

Comment: It's like custom loadouts, so the person using the class goes through a certain door, then class-specific items drop for them.

Comment: @Zommuter There is a category of map that builds "class" functionality with redstone circuits that fill your inventory with vanilla items that implement the class's abilities. No mods are required. That's what this is.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably the most compact design I know is like this:

[image: Redstone Repeater Gif]

W-W-B
W-R-T

W = Redstone Wire
B = Any solid block
R = Repeater
T = Redstone Torch

Taken from [minecraftwiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Repeater).

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to make it faster?  Decreasing delay in repeater?  Anyway to make it faster without "overclocking" the redstone torch?

Comment: Um, apart from the delay in the repeater, I don't know, sorry :(

Answer (score 4):

use a piston repeater

it works on the principle that a solid block transmits power but air doesn't moving the block disrupts/establishes the signal

Answer (score 1):

This one is very compact and can shoot 20 arrows per second.

```
L:Lever
R:Redstone
BR:redstone on block
RT:redstone torch
D:dispenser
RP:repeater

      RT-BR-RT
  L-R-R-R-R-R-R-RP-D
      RT-BR-RT
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this one. It's compact, easy and fast.

```
    B-R>-B
    D-<R-W

    D: Dispenser
    B: Block
    R: Repeater
    W: Wire

> or <: repeater direction
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to make a compact restone signal that flashes if just but doing this

```
RE-RP>-RE
RE-<RP-RE
```

`RE` = redstone wire
`RP>` or `<RP` = repeater, arrow shows the direction

after you've made this you need to power it and quickly break and place one of the wires. the trick is to wait for on of the repeaters to shut off then place the wire. this causes it to flash from one half of the device to the other. you can do this with any amount of repeaters depending on the delay you want. i found this on a youtube video but i don't remember who it was by but this is the only design i have ever used so i hope this proved useful to anyone who wants a compact flashing signal

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and most compact method that I can think of is to use two observers, two redstone dust, and two dispensers. This design takes six blocks of space, and activates a dispenser every two redstone ticks, according to my understanding of observers. Any solution that uses repeaters is likely to be slower; dispensers can face any direction. Given that dispensers will only activate every four redstone ticks we cannot fire arrows any faster without using multiple dispensers. Even the most compact designs will take a minimum of five or six blocks of spaces including redstone dust. This design is theoretically the fastest and most compact possible in the Java edition of Minecraft 1.17.

[image: Fast compact auto fire dispenser]

Comment: those comments look like they add to your own answer; I've added them directly.

Answer (score -3):

you need 3 of any blocks placed in a straight row with 3 redstone dust on top and 3 redstone torches on the back and cover those with blocks and it can empty a stack in no time